# duplicate question

Tags: support, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

My question, [mediawiki-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/mediawiki-hosting), was closed as a duplicate, but the supposedly duplicate question does not answer my question:

My question is about wiki-as-a-service, the linked question is about general web hosting.

How can I get my question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best mediawiki hosting provider?
>
> (...)
>
> There seem to be a few providers who offer this, what have you had
>   success with?

The [Pro Webmasters question guidelines](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) state that you should "avoid asking subjective questions" and, on that basis, asking which MediaWiki hosting provider is the *best* is problematic.

The secondary question is polling users for their subjective experience with different MediaWiki hosting providers - it's a perfectly valid question to start a forum thread, but StackExchange sites are intended to provide questions and answers, not discussion threads.

For clarification on the general StackExchange approach to handling shopping questions and recommendations, I would recommend [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) at the StackExchange blog (which was the inspiration for the [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) catch-all answer).

The best factual information that the Pro Webmasters community can provide is *how to search for* the hosting provider that will best suit your particular needs at a given point in time - even if everyone agreed upon a hosting provider for MediaWiki, the odds are against that hosting provider remaining the favorite (or providing the same quality of service, or providing a price that is accessible to all askers).

Comment: Thanks Dan, I see how my question was subjective. I'm used to asking in SO, where there is almost always an answer (even if that answer is "stop using windows").

Comment: @Oatman Slipped my mind in my initial reply, but I would recommend [mwusers.com](http://www.mwusers.com/forums/forum.php) as a forum for posing your question as-is for extended discussion amongst other MediaWiki users :)

Comment: Ah, thank you, that looks handy!